# Want something like Cayley formula for unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

It is known that assigning to a skew-symmetric matrix $S$ the matrix $(S-I)(S+I)^{-1}$ is one-to-one onto orthogonal matrices without nonzero fixed points (that is, with all eigenvalues $\ne1$); the inverse map assigns to an orthogonal $O$ as above the matrix $(I+O)(I-O)^{-1}$.

(To my shame I only learned about this beautiful fact from [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/90072/41291) on MO; it is called Cayley formula, although when I looked up his paper he only gives a clever description of the determinant for $S+I$ which implies that it is nonzero. Anyway, the standard reference seems to be page 289 in Gantmacher.)

Do you know if there is anything similar for **unitary** matrices? To be more specific, I want a rational function $f$ and a linear subspace $\mathscr L$ of all matrices such that the value of $f$ on any matrix from $\mathscr L$ is unitary, and "almost all" (say, outside a measure zero subset, or in a Zariski open subset, or just in a dense subset) of unitary matrices are in the image of $\mathscr L$. Of course it would be better to have explicit description of that missing set, and even better if unitarity of $f(M)$ implies $M\in\mathscr L$ but I would call this a bonus.

**Post-accept**

I've accepted the perfect answer, let me just for convenience add the link to the Wikipedia page provided by the author of the answer in a comment, adding that the map is called [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Other_matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different choices for $f$: You may use the same formula $f(S)=(S+I)(S-I)^{-1}$ but with $S^*=-S$ (hermitian conjugate). The image is unitary but $1$ can not be an eigenvalue. You may also use $f(A)=(A+i)(A-i)^{-1}$ and $A^*=A$ you map selfadjoint matrices to unitary. If you simply change signs (or multiply by a number of modulus 1) you map to unitary matrices avoiding a specific number in the spectrum. In any case the image is dense and of full measure.

Comment: OMG that simple! The same formula?! And the backwards map is also the same?

Comment: Also, do you have a reference?

Comment: No wait this does not work e. g. for $S=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: Your $S$ is self adjoint. It actually works for the second map I mentioned

Comment: You may search for 'Cayley transform,  selfadjoint', but it tends to get quite complicated. There is a wiki page  (on the bottom only it mentions the unitary case): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform

Comment: Yes, thanks, sorry! And thanks for the reference!